# Ansible creating a virtualenv

Tags: python, ansible

How do you create a virtualenv for a specific python version using ansible. Is there a command in the ansible standard library?

I would like something like:

```
- virtualenv: dest=venv python_version:/usr/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 97):

I have at times experienced some erratic behaviour with specifying `virtualenv_command` (e.g.: getting a python 2.7 executable in my virtualenv even though I specified to run the command with `virtualenv-3.4`.

If you experience that problem, you *can* create the virtualenv manually with the `command` module:

```
- name: Manually create the initial virtualenv
  command:
    cmd: virtualenv /user/home/venvs/myenv -p python3.4
    creates: "/user/home/venvs/myenv"
```

(note: by specifying `creates` this command will only run in the case that a virtualenv does not exist at `/user/home/venvs/myenv`).

Then you can install your requirements as normal with the `pip` command:

```
- name: Install requirements
  pip: 
    requirements=/my_app/requirements.txt 
    virtualenv=/user/home/venvs/myenv
```

**Update**

I've found that specifying the `virtualenv_python` (available in Ansible 2.0+) also seems to work  in the case stated above. For example:

```
- name: Install requirements
  pip: 
    requirements: /my_app/requirements.txt
    virtualenv: /user/home/venvs/myenv
    virtualenv_python: python3.4
```

(with this you shouldn't need to manually create the virtualenv first)

Comment: The last one worked for me (that way is mentioned in the docs of Ansible 2 now). Just one thing: I needed to specify `chdir` while installing `kallithea`, otherwise the current directory (which is referenced inside the `requirements.txt`) is wrong. Having `chdir=/my_app` might work here

Comment: The last two `pip` tasks don't work if you need Python 3.x inside the virtualenv and your Ansible is using Python 2.x.  Because Ansible is using Python2, it generates a `pip2 install` command that bypasses the virtualenv and will use any system-level pip installation instead - hence the packages are installed at system level not into virtualenv.  For this setup with Python 3, I had to use shell commands for creating the virtualenv and pip installation.

Comment: What did work was `shell: source "{{ app_home }}/.virtualenvs/myenv/bin/activate" && pip3 install -r "{{ app_home }}/tests/requirements.txt"`.

Comment: Please don't use `virtualenv` shell command with Python3. There it's called `pyvenv`.

Comment: FYI, ``pyvenv`` has been deprecated since Python 3.6.0. It is now ``python3 -m venv``: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score 19):

You can do it with the [`pip`](http://docs.ansible.com/pip_module.html) module and a specific `virtualenv` binary:

```
- pip: virtualenv=/path/to/venv virtualenv_command=/path/to/virtualenv3 ...
```

Comment: Doing this is asking for a name or requirements to be given. Do I need to set either of these options? Or is there a way to create an empty virtualenv

Comment: @user204088 and why would you need an empty virtualenv? Ansible pip module nicely creates one for you if it doesn't exist, or use it if it does...

Comment: You've probably figured this out already but it's asking for a name/requirements because pip needs to know what to install.  It can't be used as specified above solely for creating a virtual environment.  Instead, it creates the virtual environment in the course of installing the package(s) you specify.

Comment: @Stefano you are absolutely correct. I think the other answers here are more complete.

Answer (score 11):

With ansible 2.0 you can specify a python version for your virtualenv with `virtualenv_python`

For example:

```
- name: Initiate virtualenv
  pip: virtualenv="{{ virtualenv_dir }}" 
       virtualenv_python=python3.4
       requirements={{ app_dir }}/requirements.txt
```

Comment: it was already possible in Ansible 1.* using `virtualenv_command` eg. `virtualenv_command: "python3.4 /path/to/virtualenv" `

Comment: with ansible 3 you can specify the python interpreter version with `ansible_python_interpreter` in inventory file

Answer (score 2):

On Centos-7:

Ansible Version: 2.9 (this script should work for ansible version 2 +)

Complete ansible script to Create Python3.6 Virtual Environment

```
  - name: Enable EPEL Repository on CentOS 7
    yum:
      name: epel-release
      state: latest


  - name: check if virtualenv library already installed or not
    stat:
      path: /usr/bin/virtualenv
    register: pip_virtualenv_installed
    

  - name: Download Pip-Installer
    get_url:
      url: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py
      dest: /tmp/get-pip.py
    when: pip_virtualenv_installed.stat.exists == False


  - name: Install pip
    shell: /usr/bin/python /tmp/get-pip.py
    when: pip_virtualenv_installed.stat.exists == False


  - name: Install virtualenv module
    pip:
      name: virtualenv
    when: pip_virtualenv_installed.stat.exists == False


  - name: Install Python 3.6
    yum:
      name:
        - python36
        - python36-devel
        - python36-libs
        - python3-setuptools
        - gcc
        - gcc-c++
      state: present


  - name: Create Python3-virtual environment folder
    file:
      name: /opt/python3-virtualenv
      state: directory


  - name: Initiate virtualenv
    pip:
      virtualenv: /opt/python3-virtualenv
      virtualenv_python: python3.6
      requirements: /opt/python3-virtualenv/requirements.txt
```