# Ansible Venv Activate Permission Denied Django CMS

Tags: python, django, ansible, virtualbox, django-cms

Im making an ansible role to install a clean Django CMS instance, when trying to activate my installed Virtual Env I'm getting a permission error, I have read up that sometimes this can be caused when making the env with different permissions to when you try and activate it. I have tried with and without root sudo in both instances.

I am using a `Ubuntu/Trusty64` box.

Here is the error im getting from my task:

`TASK [dependancies : Activate Venv] ********************************************
fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ". env/bin/activate", "failed": true, "msg": "[Errno 13] Permission denied", "rc": 13}`

Here is my role file:

```
---
- name: Update apt-get
  become: yes
  apt:
    update_cache: yes

- name: Install Packages
  apt:
    name: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - nginx
    - python3
    - python-pip
    - nodejs
    - git
    - python-passlib # for htpasswd
    - postgresql
    - libpq-dev # for postgresql
    - python-psycopg2 # for postgresql
    - ansible # to run ansible-pull
  become: yes

- name: Install Python Libraries
  pip:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    executable: pip
  become: yes
  with_items:
    - virtualenv
    - awscli # for backups

- name: Create Venv
  command: virtualenv env
  args:
    creates: env/bin/activate

- name: Activate Venv
  command: . env/bin/activate

- name: Install Django-CMS Insaller
  pip:
    name: djangocms-installer
    executable: pip

- name: Create Folder
  file: path=django state=directory

- name: Create Django CMS
  command: djangocms -s -p . testSite
  args:
    chdir: django
  become: yes
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible creating a virtualenv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402123/ansible-creating-a-virtualenv)

Comment: You can't use `activate` this way, because each Ansible task is a different session.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov Thanks for the response, I have tried running the following task: `- name: Install Django-CMS Insaller
  command: . env/bin/activate && pip install djangocms-installer
  become: yes` But it is still saying permission denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do it this way in the first place!

Use `pip` package with `virtualenv` parameters. If you still want to activate. See example in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402123/ansible-creating-a-virtualenv).

If you still want to activate virtual environment inside a shell, you should use `shell` module (not `command`!) for `source bin/activate` to work. `source` and `.` are bash built-ins, so `command` module can't execute them.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, on closer inspection of the pip documentation I should have taken this approach in the first place, it has fixed installing the Python Packages in the venv but I'm still trying to get the djangocms installer to work.